# How to have a data validation in access?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, access, excel-access-web-part

I have an Access App linked to SharePoint, there are few columns of data, there is a particular dropdown list created by lookup manually inserted values.

What I want is, the dropdown list when selected should return a value in next column.

Example:

I have a dropdown list with values

Column 1:

```
Project Manager <Drop Down List>    
AAAAAA                              
DDDDDD
CCCCCC
```

Column 2:

```
Reporting Head <Want Result here>
<this should printed Automatically from Project manager selected>
<I want the project manager's reporting head's name printed automatically here>
```